# google.maps.Circle snap to nearest mile

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Created some functionality in google v3 api where users can drop a pin. Once they drop a pin an editable circle is created with the pin as the center. They can expand the circle and see the distance which pops up in an infowindow. The issue is that it is difficult to get to the nearest mile or half mile. I will try to get it to the nearest mile by dragging the circle and it gets to like 10.23 miles...

Does anyone have recommendation about this? 
   http://jsfiddle.net/wa8s0dya/

```
//create circle
    function createCircle() {
        if ((circle != null) && circle.setMap) {
            circle.setMap(null);
            circle = null;
        }
        var options = {
            strokeColor: '#0099FF',
            strokeOpacity: 0.8,
            strokeWeight: 2,
            fillColor: '#0099FF',
            fillOpacity: 0.35,
            map: map,
            center: marker.getPosition(),
            editable: true,
            radius: 500

        };

        // Add the circle for this city to the map.
        circle = new google.maps.Circle(options);
        google.maps.event.addListener(circle, 'radius_changed', function () {
            removeInfoWindow();
            popUpPinInfo(marker, circle.radius, map);
        });

        google.maps.event.addListener(circle, 'circlecomplete', function () {
            removeInfoWindow();
            popUpPinInfo(marker, circle.radius, map);
        });


    }
```

Comment: Please post a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) that demonstrates the issue wouldn't hurt as well).  The code posted doesn't include the map.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One mile is 1609.34 meters (the circle's radius is defined in meters).

To make the circle size in increments of 1 mile, you need to make the radius (the +8m causes it to not get rounded down to .99 miles):

```
circle.setRadius(circle.getRadius() - (circle.getRadius() % 1609.34)+8);
```

Whenever the radius changes:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(circle, 'radius_changed', function () {
  if ((circle.getRadius() % 1609.34) > 160) {
      circle.setRadius(circle.getRadius() - (circle.getRadius() % 1609.34)+8) // meters per mile 
  }
  removeInfoWindow();
  popUpPinInfo(marker, circle.radius, map);
});
google.maps.event.addListener(circle, 'circlecomplete', function () {
  circle.setRadius(circle.getRadius() - (circle.getRadius() % 1609.34)+8) // meters per mile 
  removeInfoWindow();
  popUpPinInfo(marker, circle.radius, map);
});
```

[updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wa8s0dya/1/)